# apply mask on a matrix by matlab command

Tags: matlab

I try to pass a column vector as a mask onto a matrix  using Matlab , the operation is multiplying the values of the matrix with the values of mask , not that mask have three values as following explanation :

```matlab
matrix = [1 3 5 2; 2 4 6 3; 7 8 10 1;3 5 4 2;2 4 6 3];
b=[2 3 4];
mask=b(:);
disp(matrix)
disp(mask)
[row, col] = size(matrix);

for j=1:col
    i=1;
    g=1;
    while((i<=row))
        if (g<=3)
            matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)*mask(g);
            g=g+1;
        else
            g=1;
            matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)*mask(g);
            g=g+1;
        end
        i=i+1;
    end
end

disp(matrix)
```

the output is:

```
     2     6    10     4
     6    12    18     9
    28    32    40     4
     6    10     8     4
     6    12    18     9
```

Comment: That's not a mask. Also, please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: @beaker , Tanks for your  fast response. I don't know if this this a mask or not, but it called mask in the proposed research. My question was how to apply tis vector on on matrix by multiply three column values  from the matrix.

Comment: Which values of the matrix are multiplied by each value of the vector? What results do you expect for each of the examples you gave? What code have you tried to achieve this operation?

Comment: I want the following: link italic bold ` matrix = [1 3 5 2 ; 2 4 6 3 ; 7 8 10 1;3 5 4 2;2 4 6 3;3 4 2 3]; and mask=[2 3 4] , mask is column vector , after count matrix * mask .I want the result be as follow: the new matrix= 2 6 10 4 ;6 12 18 9; 28 32 40 4; 6 10 8 4; 6 12 18 9; 12 16 8 12`

Comment: Please add updates to your original question using [edit]. Comments are temporary and cannot be formatted properly for code and data. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you @beaker , that a good answer ,but it till now un clear for me , I must reading about your code. Today I reach to another way that gave the same results of your one. I wrote it in the original post. Tell me if that a right thing. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A=[1 3 5 2 ; 2 4 6 3 ; 7 8 10 1;3 5 4 2;2 4 6 3;3 4 2 3]
b=[2 3 4]

b2=repmat(b,1,floor(size(A,1)/numel(b)))';

% in case mod(size(A,1),numel(b))~=0
if mod(size(A,1),numel(b))
    b2=[b2;b([1:mod(size(A,1),numel(b))])'];
end

A.*b2
```

this produces the expected

```
=
     2     6    10     4
     6    12    18     9
    28    32    40     4
     6    10     8     4
     6    12    18     9
    12    16     8    12
```

and it also works for any length of `b` whether `numel(b)` being multiple `size(A,1)` or any other size,  `numel(b)` being shorter than `size(A,1)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [times operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) `.*` which multiplies corresponding elements in matrices/vectors.

For your second example, this is straightforward because the matrix has the same number of rows as the elements in the vector:

```matlab
a = [1 3 5 4; 2 4 6 2; 7 8 10 1;2 4 1 3];
b = [2 4 6 3];
c = reshape(b,[],1); 

r = a .* c;

r = 
    2    6   10    8
    8   16   24    8
   42   48   60    6
    6   12    3    9
```

For a matrix that has more (or fewer) rows than the vector, you'll need to repeat the elements appropriately. I'm going to change the matrix in your last example (currently in the comments) to have 5 rows instead of 6 to show the general case.

```matlab
a = [1 3 5 2; 2 4 6 3; 7 8 10 1; 3 5 4 2; 2 4 6 3];
b = [2 3 4];
c = reshape(b,[],1);
% now extend c to the proper length
m = size(a,1);
k = size(c,1);
c = repmat(c,ceil(m/k),1);   % duplicate c to make its size >= m
c = c(1:m,1);   % then trim it

r = a .* c;

r = 
    2    6   10    4
    6   12   18    9
   28   32   40    4
    6   10    8    4
    6   12   18    9
```

Answer (score 0):

**slicing** is another word for **reading** or **extracting** matrix values along a certain coordinate kept constant.

A 3D matrix can be sliced along a plane, thus resembling a slicing, like when preparing breakfast and slicing bread.

2D matrices have **columns = vertical** and **rows = horizontal**.

```
A=[1 2 3 4;5 4 2 1; 3 2 1 6;2 1 5 7]
b=[1 2 3]
```

**1.- Extract Columns**

```
A(:,b)
```

Reading a single column, for instance column 3, would be

```
A(:,3)
```

**2.- Extract Rows**

Extracting 1st 3 rows

```
A(b,:)
```

Extracting 4th row

```
A(4,:)
```

Some people use the word line instead of row, but it may be really misleading in some cases, as a line can be vertical or horizontal, so let's use Mathworks terms.

**3.- `disp(A)` and `A` are the same**

`disp` is mainly used to display text in the command line.

For instance `disp('error 404 .. bla bla')`

One can insert these warnings in places where if reached, it's probable that there's a problem, and a quick text message may help understand why the program got there.

But to read `A` in command line, just key in `A`.

One can also ready variable contents in the **Workspace** directly clicking on each variable.

**4.- `c=reshape(b,[],1)` same as `b'`**

Again, it's useful to keep coding as simple as possible, particularly when the size of the programs start to grow.

So for this particular case, `b'` suffices.

**5.- MATLAB introductory courses**

I suggest you have a look at Mathworks free introductory courses available online here:

https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/?s_tid=srchtitle_matlab%20on%20ramp_1

This is a self-paced structured way to build knowledge that covers all the corners and basics regarding **MATLAB**.

**Good thinks always come in pairs: **SIMULINK** is also really useful.**

To get started with **SIMULINK** on-ramp courses also available [here](https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/?s_tid=srchtitle_matlab%20on%20ramp_1#simulink).

**6.- mask on matrix**

An example of a mask on `A` would be a mask to select all elements of `A` equal to 1 :

```
A==1
 =
  4×4 logical array
   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1
   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0
```

to find the 2D coordinates of all elements of A==1 one can do the following :

```
[row,col]=find(A==1)
row =
     1
     4
     3
     2
col =
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

these are elements `[1 1]` `[4 2]` `[3 3]` and `[2 4]`

But MATLAB as another simpler way to define elements in a matrix, with a single coordinate: the linear index.

If you do

```
find(A==1)
 =
     1
     8
    11
    14
```

These are again exactly the same elements, but having assigned a single index starting top left, reading column down, and then on to next column to the right.

Read more about **Matrix Indexing** here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?s_tid=srchtitle_matrix%20indexing_1

Comment: Thanks for your fast response  . Sorry, slicing was a printing error , because I meant (sliding)

Comment: In short, I want the following:        [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** ` matrix = [1 3 5 2 ; 2 4 6 3 ; 7 8 10 1;3 5 4 2;2 4 6 3;3 4 2 3];
 and mask=[2 3 4] , mask is column vector   , after count matrix * mask .I want the result be as follow:  the new matrix=       `

Comment: the new matrix= 2 6 10 4 ;6 12 18 9; 28 32 40 4; 6 10 8 4; 6 12 18 9; 12 16 8 12